# On average, how many midi-chlorians are present in non-force-sensitive?

Tags: star-wars

I always thought non-force-sensitives contain zero midi-chlorian. But, then I watched *Star Wars: The Clone Wars - The Lost Missions (Unfinished season 6)*. In an episode, Jar-Jar was attacked for force extraction from him. Upon arguing that he wasn't force-sensitive, he got reply that everyone has small amount of Force. I don't know what containing the Force means. But, It looks like he must have midi-chlorians which is directly related with the Force sensitivity.

How many midi-chlorians can be found in a non-force-sensitive?

Comment: "Well, the Force is what gives a Jedi his power. It's an energy field created by all living things. It surrounds us and penetrates us. It binds the galaxy together." Straight from ANH, the Force is in/created by all living things. The introduction of midichlorians doesn't contradict that.

Comment: The Star Wars Wikia suggests that a base level is approx 2500 midi-chlorians in non-force sensitive creatures; http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian

Comment: Enough to make it worthwhile to subject someone to a painful extraction process.  Though, as it's Jar Jar, that number wouldn't have to be very high.

Comment: Did he die? Tell me he died...

Comment: @phantom42: also "Life creates it, makes it grow. Its energy surrounds us and binds us", straight from ESB and totally consistent with the ANH quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the novel Death Star, non-force sensitive's had approximately 2,000 midi-chlorians per cell. Mild sensitivity to the force was 5,000  and since Jar Jar had a large amount of "luck" surviving dangerous situations, I'd say he might have a slightly higher count, though not enough to use Force powers.

Comment: So we have the midichlorians to blame for Jarjar?

Comment: Ha.. Ha.. Luck is also a force power?

Comment: Luck for HIM, maybe...

Comment: The real question is how many did Han Solo have? He may have the highest midichlorian count of everyone.

Comment: If we're basing this on "Luck" then I have 3 midichlorians, two of which are rather poorly.  It also explains why I was never able to block those rocks my brother kept throwing at me!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Owen and Beru are the poster-children for non-Force sensitives, we see in the (Legends<sup>*</sup>) factbook [*Star Wars: Graphics*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Graphics) that a good average for a bog standard human is somewhere between 1500 and 3300.

> [image]

<sup>*</sup>Note that these figures seem to have been taken from the [fake midi-chlorian numbers](https://web.archive.org/web/20050204223101/http://www.supershadow.com/starwars/midi.html) invented by [infamous Star Wars fabulist SuperShadow](https://web.archive.org/web/20200308021521/https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/SuperShadow) and should be treated with caution.

Answer (score -1):

There are no definitive midichlorian numbers I think. To get better idea, how midichlorians work I suggest to look into [mitochondria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondria). Mitochondria are obvious inspiration for midichlorians, being part of our cells that were autonomous organisms (like bacteria) long time ago.

That and following episodes should provide better understanding of the Force, but it is important to keep in mind, that the Force is not 100% understood in the story. It is not meant to be easily explainable and comprehensible (maybe that is why all the midichlorian business upset so many people).